# Google Web Starter Kit not installing correctly

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, starter-kits

i tried to install GWSKdownloaded it and used `sudo npm install`afetr a while i got an error

```
`darwin-x64-node-0.10` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
npm ERR! cb() never called!
```

I ignored it and continued two more dependencies where missing concat-map and balanced-match so I installed them manually.

when I run `gulp serve` I get the following error:

```
[10:17:10] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/Sitios/bill/gulpfile.js
[10:17:10] Starting 'styles'...
[10:17:11] 'styles' errored after 1.23 s
[10:17:11] TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'rubySass'
at Gulp.gulp.task.$.useref.assets.searchPath (/Users/mercadotecnia/Desktop/Sitios/bill/gulpfile.js:91:13)
at module.exports (/Users/mercadotecnia/Desktop/Sitios/bill/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/mercadotecnia/Desktop/Sitios/bill/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/mercadotecnia/Desktop/Sitios/bill/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/mercadotecnia/Desktop/Sitios/bill/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:929:3
```

Answer (score 0):

ok updated node and reinstalled gulp and everything works fine again posting answer incase sombody has the same issue.